# how to change props value using method - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am quite new in vue and working on a task which is based on vue.js. I am showing my data in a component using a prop. Now I want to add a method to increment the quantity of a product.

here is my code:

```
<div v-for="(products, index) in products">
  <mdc-layout-cell span="2" align="middle">
    {{ products.product_barcode }}
  </mdc-layout-cell>
<mdc-layout-cell span="2" align="middle">
  {{ products.product_quantity}}
</mdc-layout-cell>
<i class="mdc-icon-toggle material-icons float-left"
   aria-pressed="false"
   v-on:click="incrementItem(index)">
  add
</div>
```

here is my JS:

```
export default {
    props: [
      'products',
    ],
    methods: {

      incrementItem(index) {
        let item = this.products[index];
        this.products[index].product_quantity =
          this.products[index].product_quantity + 1;
          console.log(this.products[index].product_quantity);
      },
    }
```

I can see the incremented value in the console, but the value is not increasing in the respective row. How could I increment the value of product_quantity? Any help would be highly appreciable

Comment: Please share the code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign `props` value to a variable. Then use it child component.

```
export default {
    props: {
      products: Array,
    },
    data(){
     return {
       newProducts: this.products,
     }
   }
}
```

You should change `props` structure in child component. use `newProducts` in child component and if you update parent props data you should use `emit` for child to parent communication.

For further parent child communication you can follow this tutorial:
https://www.bdtunnel.com/2018/02/vue-js-component-communication-complete.html

Comment: I have another question I want to add another value in newProducts array and show in component i.e current_quantity by subtracting two quantities i.e stock_in and quantity that are available in products.

Answer (score 5):

**First, in terms of vue flow, remember never mutating directly props**. You should mutate the data in the parent component instead. To do this, the recommendation is to create a copy of props in children data so when click at the button, the children data change -> the parents data change, which makes the children props also change. There are many ways to do this. I dont have you parents component code so i make a generic code below, you can follow:

**using sync**

in parents components

```
<parent :products.sync=products />
```

in children components methods:

```js
data() {
  return {
    productListInChildren: this.products; // pass props to children inner data
  }
},
methods: {
    incrementItem(index) {
       //do modification in productListInChildren
       let item = this.productListInChildren[index];
        this.productListInChildren[index].product_quantity =
          this.productListInChildren[index].product_quantity + 1;
        // update it back to parents
        this.$emit('update:products', this.productListInChildren)
  }
}
```

```html
<div v-for="(products, index) in productListInChildren"> // use productListInChildren instead
  <mdc-layout-cell span="2" align="middle">
    {{ products.product_barcode }}
  </mdc-layout-cell>
  <mdc-layout-cell span="2" align="middle">
    {{ products.product_quantity}}
  </mdc-layout-cell>
  <i class="mdc-icon-toggle material-icons float-left"
     aria-pressed="false"
     v-on:click="incrementItem(index)">
    add </i>
</div>
```

**Second: in terms of code design, it is recommended in your case, the children should only handle the logic of display (dumb component)**. Logic of changing data should be moved to parents (like a controller). If that is the case. you can create a method in parents component and add the increment logic:

parents components

```
<parent :products=products @increment="incrementInParent"/>



methods: {
incrementInParent() {// move the logic here}
}
```

children components

```
methods: {
    incrementItem(index) {
       // call the methods in parents
       this.$emit("increment");
  }
}
```

Comment: "Remember never mutating directly props"... but we *can* make mistakes and modify them without intention. The fact that Vue (even in v3) allows mutation of prop (the fields under them) is a *huge* footgun. I hate to say this, but this doesn't happen in React, because the props are truly `readonly`.

Comment: As you write `let item = this.productListInChildren[index]`, why not just `item.product_quantity += 1`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never mutate props in the child component. You should use event communication pattern for child and parent communication.
While changing a particular value inside an array in particular index in an array or updating a property in an object the view does not react to these changes due to Object and Array Caveats in Vue.
You can read it here

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

You can use `$set` to make the template react to changes in Object and Array.
Here is my sandbox URL which answers your question

[image: Edit patient-brook-nf1w5]